# Firestore only saves certain fields from a custom object

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to save a custom object to Firestore, but for some reason it is not working properly:

```
abstract class AbstractModel(open val id: String) {}
class ConcreteModel(override val id: String, private val username: String, private val password: String) : AbstractModel(id) {}

fun save() {
  val newModel = ConcreteModel("id", "username", "password")
  val db = Firebase.firestore
  db.collection("collection").document(newModel.id).set(newModel)
}
```

It only saves the `id` and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that Firestore won't persist `private` fields, so I would suggest keeping their visibility public.

---

A way to still keep your fields private would be to [persist the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) using a map, for example:

```
hashMapOf(
    "id" to newModel.id,
    "username" to newModel.username,
    "password" to newModel.password
)
```

Comment: It worked! It would have taken me forever to figure that out. Is there any way to keep them private and still make it work?

Comment: Well you can manually convert your object to a map, but I don't think there's a way to automate the process unfortunately.

Comment: Would you keep it as an object and just save it or make it into a map? Is any of these a preferred solution?

Comment: I personally map all my objects, just so I have more control and assurance of what is being persisted and what isn't, but I don't think there is a preferred way, whatever makes the most sense to you and produces the cleanest code!

Comment: If I want to map, do I have to use something like Jackson or Gson or Kotlin has something built in to for this?

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: I see... but that will only make things harder if I want to change the structure of the model, since I laos have to change the hashMapOf. Thanks for the help anyway.